# post command not called to controller using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC framework to post submit the data from the jsp to the controller defined with mappings in the dispatcher-servlet.xml.

but the controller is called only during the load, i mean when i during the load of the page..

when i click on submit in the jsp page, onsubmit in the controller is never hit...

could you please help me around what the issue..

### index.jsp

```
<form form method="post"  commandName="postsubmit">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>cal pool: </b></td>  <td> <input type="text"> </input> </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td> <b>date: </b></td>  <td> <input type="text"> </input> </td>
            </tr>
            </br>
            </br>
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="submit"/> </td>

            </tr>

        </table>
        </form>
```

### dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean name="/index.htm" class="PostSubmitController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="postsubmit"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="PostSubmit"/>
    <property name="formView" value="index"/>
    <property name="successView" value="success.htm"/> 
    <property name="postSubmit" ref="postSubmit"/>

</bean>
```

## PostSubmitController

```
public class PostSubmitController extends SimpleFormController{
   private PostSubmit _postsubmit; 

   protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 

     public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
            throws ServletException { 
         System.out.println("hello");
         logger.info("debug1");
        String _getcal_pool = ((PostSubmit) command).getCal_pool();
        logger.info("debug2");
        Date _getcal_date = ((PostSubmit) command).getDate();
        logger.info("debug3");
        logger.info("get_cal_pool:" +   _getcal_pool );
        logger.info("get_cal_date:" +   _getcal_date.toString() );
        logger.info("debug4");
        logger.info("returning from PostSubmitController view to " + getSuccessView()); 
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
   } 

    public void setPostSubmit(PostSubmit postSubmit) {
        System.out.println("hello");
         logger.info("debug5");
        this._postsubmit = postSubmit;
    } 
    public PostSubmit getPostSubmit() {
         System.out.println("hello");
         logger.info("debug6");
        return _postsubmit;
    } 

public ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response,
                                         Object command,
                                         BindException errors)
                                  throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("hello in processFormSubmission");
    logger.info("returning from processFormSubmission view to " + getSuccessView()); 
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you have to use  tag given by html, or  tag given by spring. The fist line of index.jsp  is syntactically wrong. Make it as , and try again.

Comment: i had modified the tag as <form:form> </form:form>, but still the controller is not called after the post button is clicked

Comment: you can find the form submission errors by override the following method. protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors){} once go through this

Comment: i added this part of code for the submission errors, but when i click on submit still the lines in the processFormsubmission is not reached.